# Non-empty size information for cell arrays

Tags: arrays, list, matlab, polyline, cell-array

In MATLAB I would like to keep a list of **polylines** - containing vertices (x,y) - in a container and I thought the best idea is to use **cell arrays** for this task. Each line would be represented in a row in a cell array, with vertices (x,y) being the elements of the cells. The different lines would be of different length, that's why I thought it would be a good idea to use cell arrays.

My problem however is that I don't know **how can I append to the first non-empty element of each row in a cell-array?**

Here is an example:

```
cell{1,1} = 1
cell{2,1} = 2
cell{3,1} = 3
cell{2,2} = 4
cell{2,3} = 5

cell =

    [1]     []     []
    [2]    [4]    [5]
    [3]     []     []
```

For example now I want to append a new element to the end of row 1, and another one to row 2. **How do I know what is the first position where I can append a new element?**

Or shell I use **cell arrays inside cell arrays** for this task?

**How would you implement a container for a list of polylines MATLAB?**

Comment: What about a cell of arrays? `c= {[1], [2 4 5], [3]};`. It should not be very performant but it's easy to use. Do you need to perform operations other than reading and storing new points?

Comment: You say you want to store vertices `(x,y)`, but then put only integer numbers into your cell array. Are those indices to vertices stored elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad way to store your data, for the very problems you're encountering. A couple notes:

1. The first column is used as an index (i.e. 1 for polyline 1, 2 for polyline 2, etc.), which is unnecessary since that info is already stored implicitly in the structure of your data.
2. With this method, points will have to be stacked *next* to each other, which will be a nightmare for indexing.
3. With each x and y in a different cell, it's going to be an unneeded hassle to plot/store even a single point.

There are 2 good ways to store all this information.

1. **Cell array**: Like Clement pointed out, this is nice and simple, and will let you stack different points in the same polyline along a second dimension.

   ```
   celldata = {[] [4 5] []};
   celldata{2} = [celldata{2}; 1 1];
   celldata{3} = [0.5 0.5];

   >> celldata

   celldata = 

        []    [2x2 double]    [1x2 double]
   ```
2. **Structure array**: This is a nice way to go if you want to store polyline-level metadata along with your points.

   ```
   strucdata = struct('points', {[] [4 5] []}, 'info', {'blah', 'blah', 'blah'});
   strucdata(2).points = [strucdata(2).points; 1 1];
   strucdata(3).points = [0.5 0.5];

   >> strucdata

   strucdata = 

   1x3 struct array with fields:
       points
       info

   >> strucdata(2)

   ans = 

       points: [2x2 double]
         info: 'blah'
   ```

Comment: I ended up using a struct for the vertices, a cell array for a single line and a cell array for all the lines. I think this way it's quite clear and efficient. What do you think? http://pastebin.com/uKC98Ym7

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you can use this:

```
n=1;
length([cell{n,:}])+1
n=2;
length([cell{n,:}])+1
```

With `[...]` you treat the cell slice as an array and not several scalar values.